# Remote search not working in eclipse RSE

Tags: eclipse, remote-server

I'm trying to search for a string in eclipse. I'm currently connected to a remote linux server using RSE. but the search doesn't yield any results. I'm sure that the string is present in some of the files in the directories I'm searching in. I have search in sub-folder options checked.
Any setting I need to change for it search successfully?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Eclipse are you using and which protocol do you use for your connection (ssh, ftp, or dstore)? In addition, it would be good to know which kind of project you are working on (Java, C/C++, ...). From what you stated in your question, I would guess that your project is not fully indexed yet so that most of the files are not being searched. Try rebuilding your index and see if this helps.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705  I use ssh protocol for the connection. How should rebuild the index ?

Comment: Ok, the indexing didn't work for me either when working remotely on C++ projects. But, anyway, you can try to rebuild the index by changing to the Project Explorer view, right-clicking on the project name and choose Index > Rebuild. Alternatively, you can also try to use some of the other options available there. To check if indexing works, choose Window > Show View > Other... > C/C++ > C/C++ Index. If you see a whole bunch of symbols being indexing, it should have worked correctly. Btw, Helios is quite antique, you should also try upgrading to a more recent version.

Comment: Another option worth to try is to use a different protocol for connecting. In some other posts, I read that the DStore protocol offers far more functionality than ftp or ssh do. Check this [link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftbeginlinux.html) for setup.

Answer (score 0):

You are best advised to permanently forget about searching in remote repositories using Eclipse RSE. **Remote Search requires running a dedicated daemon on the remote server**, so unless you own the server and have root access (necessary for launching daemons and opening ports on the firewall), remote searching functionality will be unavailable to you, full stop.

It eludes me why RSE doesn't just use find | grep over SSH. </rant>